# Outlook Forms Collection Item can not be disabled

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook plugin using add-in-express. I have added an adxOlFormsManager there. Which contains a Forms collection named ‘adxOlFormsCollectionItem1’.

I need to enable and disable that using two ribbon buttons. I wrote following code. adxOlFormsCollectionItem1.Enabled = false; code is capable of disable the adxOlFormsCollectionItem1. But when I change it as adxOlFormsCollectionItem2.Enabled = true; it doesn’t enable adxOlFormsCollectionItem1. Please advice me.

Here is the sample code

```
 private void adxRibbonButton1_OnClick(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
        {
            adxOlFormsCollectionItem1.Enabled = false; // Hide the pane :-)

        }

 private void adxRibbonButton2_OnClick(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
        {
            adxOlFormsCollectionItem1.Enabled = true; // does nothing  :-(
        }
```

Kushan Randima

Comment: what do you mean for `Not Working`? does it compile but nothing happens?

Comment: Yes, it does compile. Enabled = false; hides the pane. But Enabled = true; does not show the pane again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest asking Add-in Express specific questions on [their forum](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/list.php?FID=5) instead.

The collection item doesn't represent an instance of the form. The [Controlling Outlook region’s state and form’s size in Add-in Express 2010](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2010/06/25/outlook-regions-forms-size-state/) article describes the basics. Also you may find the [Outlook views and forms](https://www.add-in-express.com/support/addin-c-sharp.php#form-regions) section with sample projects helpful.